# Find an open cover for $(1,5]$ that has no finite sub-cover.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I want to find an open cover for $(1,5]$ that has no finite sub-cover.

Edit: Proof attempt: I want to prove that $\{(1+\frac{1}{n},6):n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a set of open intervals that form a cover for A=$(1,5]$, s.t. $n \in N$. let's suppose by contradiction that $\{(1+\frac{1}{n},6):n\in\mathbb N\}$ isn't a cover, that means that there is such an $x \in A$ such that there is no $I \in  ${(1+\frac{1}{n},6):n\in\mathbb N}$$ (I subcover) that includes $x$. but if we look at $(1,5]$, every real number in that interval could be covered by a sub-cover of ${(1+\frac{1}{n},6):n\in\mathbb N}$ by choosing the right $n$ and we know that $n$ goes to $\infty$ so we wouldn't have a problem covering $x$. Contradiction. and because we can't cover all $(1,5]$ only by one subcover, there is no finite subcover.

Comment: That does not work, because any one of the intervals given is already a cover.  Try $(1+\frac{1}{n},6)$ instead.

Comment: If you want sets that are open in the space $(1,5]$, you can consider $U_n = (1+\frac1n,5]$. (I corrected my comment after seeing @vadim123's comment. I didn't notice that your left endpoint was on the wrong side. -- +1 for vadim)

Comment: can you look at my proof attempt and see if its legible?

Comment: You haven't addressed in your proof why it is that there is no finite subcover.

Comment: @rogerl  okay, because you can't cover all $(1,5]$ only by one subcover. I added that to my own sketch and I thought its intuitive. show I formalize this by mathematical  tools?

Comment: Suppose for contradiction that there's a finite subcover, which means there's some largest $n$ you're using for $\left( 1 + \frac 1 n, 5\right ]$. Why is that a problem?

Comment: your notation is confusing. You probably understand that a cover is a family of intervals, not just one interval, but you didn't write it properly. Or perhaps you need to see the correct notation to understand this problem. The cover is $\{(1+\frac{1}{n},6):n\in\mathbb N\}$. For a finite subcover, you pick finite $F\subset\mathbb N$, your finite (would be) subcover is $\{(1+\frac{1}{n},6):n\in\mathbb F\}$. Could you argue that the latter cannot possibly cover $(1,5]$? (There would be a largest $n\in F$.)